# installing wordpress in a directory parallel to the domain root

Tags: php, wordpress

I eventually want to setup wordpress multisite, but first I'm trying to move my existing site to a separate wordpress folder. So in my shared hosting server, I've setup the following structure

```
www/domainname/

www/wordpress/
```

I've moved the wordpress installation to wordpress folder. I've setup my cPanel hosting to redirect all requests to `http://www.domainname.com` to the domainname folder. domainname folder has its own `.htaccess` and index.php files.

Now in index.php, I edited the following:

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

But all requests to http://www.domainname.com give the error that it can't find the file:
'`/home/username/public_html/domainname/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php`'

I also tried to set the path as '`../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php`' but it didn't work either.

Comment: There are instructions in the WordPress codex for installing into a subdirectory.

Comment: Here's the Codex article: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: the problem I have is that wordpress installation is not in a subdirectory, but a directory parallel to the domain's root. My cPanel settings automatically redirect all requests to www.domainname.com to www/domainname directory. Wordpress installation sits parallel to it.